# Pass Emacs buffer to C

Tags: c, emacs

I want to write a C program that takes in a region of an Emacs buffer and replaces the region with its output.

Here is my C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("The argument given was: %s\n",argv[1]);
}
```

I compile this with

```
g++ -Wall -o c_example c_example.c
```

and put the binary in my path.  When I do

```
c_example Hello
```

in the terminal, I get

```
The argument given was: Hello
```

but if I select "Hello" in an Emacs buffer and use shell-command-on-region with "C-u M-| c_example" it is replaced with

```
The argument given was: (null)
```

instead.  Why is this?

Comment: Not an Emacs user, but I guess that pipe character means you are piping the buffer as standard input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents of an emacs buffer passed to the `filter` command is not retrieved from the command line, but from standard input.  You are supposed to read it with `fgets()`, or any of the other input functions from `<stdio.h>`.

Try this version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[80];
    if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        printf("The first line of the buffer is: %s", line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```